# Accept inputs from the user until 5 unique inputs

Tags: python

How would I do this using a while function. Do we have to use a set somewhere for this?

This is what I have so far

```
while True:
    mySet = set(input("Enter a number:"))
    if mySet == 5:
        break
    print(mySet)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three main issues here:

1. Using the [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) constructor on an interable will create a set from its elements. In this case, the string returned from `input`. So for example:

   ```
   >>> set("hello")
   {'h', 'o', 'e', 'l'}
   >>> set("54")
   {'5', '4'}
   ```

   Not sure this is what you want. If you want to consider the input **as a whole**, you will have to use the [`add`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.add) method of sets.
2. Secondly, you are re-initiazling your `set` on each input (as described above). Again, not sure this is what you actually want. You will have to initialize the set **once, outside** the loop.
3. You are checking if the "set" is actually the integer `5`. What you probably meant, was to use [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) to check if `len(mySet) == 5`

---

All together a sample code could be:

```py
my_set = set()
while len(my_set) != 5:
    my_set.add(input("Enter a number:"))
    print(my_set)
```

---

If you expect the input to be numbers, and want to store them as such, you can change to: `mySet.add(int(input("Enter a number:")))` but keep in mind that this now might raise an exception so some error handling might be in place.

Comment: Good analysis. I think you also want to convert the user input to an int before adding to your set. Actually.. nevermind.. you don't really need that in an example. doesn't matter if the set stores a string or an int value. It will still disallow duplicates.

Comment: @Todd yeah I did only notice halfway through writing the answer that the input prompt actually says "Enter a number". Until that point I thought of it as general input. In that case some clarification on the exact input structure is needed from OP, but still this should work as intended

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried something similar before posting the question but I didnt have the myset.add function in there. I tried append instead which did not work.

Comment: what exception would be raised in the 2nd block of code that you have? you require an `int(...)))` when taking in the input into the set? then it would raise `ValueError` a base 10 error if user ever entered a `string` or a `char` letter

Comment: @FishingCode because this is based on user input, you can't guarentee it will always match your expected pattern, so if the user inputs, for example, `five`, then `int('five')` will raise a `ValueError`

Comment: right, so this is also missing a try/except nest for the input to be within...and if you do a `raise ValueError as e:` without the int and with an example like you're providing `five` you do not get a `ValueError` exception..the code requires `int()` in your code.

Comment: @FishingCode I am not sure I follow. I simply added it as a note to have my answer general for having 5 unique inputs. In case those inputs are ints a conversion is needed which might raise an error. I didn't add a `try/except` block because it doesn't seem to be the main point here

Comment: ah ok, yes, no you have it all good :) I thought you meant your code was going to raise an exception if anything but an `int` was entered but when I test it in any case it wouldn't raise an exception unless you want to add the `try/except` and really want to handle some error handling...

Answer (score 1):

Right now your stumbling block might be in this comparison:

```
if mySet == 5:
```

That line, as written, asks if the variable `mySet`, which may contain zero, one, two, or many more different elements, is equal to the integer 5.  But `mySet` isn't an integer itself--it is a `set` object--so it will probably never be equal to 5.

If we want to know if there are exactly five unique elements in the set, we can use Python's built-in `len` keyword, which gives the length of a collection (for example, the length of a `set`, but also possibly the length of a `list` or a `tuple`.)

```
>mySet = set([1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5])
>print(mySet)
set([1,2,3,4,5])
>len(mySet)
5
```

Something else to think about, though, is that you overwrite `mySet` every time you iterate your `while` loop.  This line `mySet = set(input("Enter a number:"))` will overwrite the value of `mySet` with each new user input.  With your current "Enter a number:" prompt, the user may only enter one value at a time.  Maybe the user will never enter exactly five unique numbers!  In this case you may want to prompt the user differently ("Enter five unique numbers: ") or look at options on how to add or remove elements from a set.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand how 'len' might be useful in counting the numbers in the set. Another problem I have is that I cant add numbers to the set one by one. Instead it asks for the numbers all at once.

Comment: If you want the user to enter elements into the set one at a time, you can start with an empty set (mySet = set() )and then use the .add() method of sets to add new elements. ( mySet.add(4) )

Answer (score 0):

This maybe another good option, doesn't make use of a `set()`though, set() can be used as well like shown in the other answers, but here's one by using a list. Hope it helps :)

```
x = []
getUnique = []
while True:
   getNum = int(input("Enter a number:"))
   x.append(getNum)
   for num in x:
      if num not in getUnique: 
         getUnique.append(num)
   if len(getUnique) == 5:
      print('5 unique numbers in list')
      print(getUnique) #shows only 5 unique numbers from user input.
      break
```